# How to set beckground image full div without using height

Tags: html, css

I have first div generated dynamically and second div I have placed it.

First div image is taking 200X200 by dynamically. Same size image i want to set it through css in second div.

But when I tried to set it and it's not taking full height 200 of the image.
If i mention min-height it's not coming properly for all resolutions. I don't want to specify min-height for the media queries.

How to set background image height automatically?

First Div structure

```
<div class="product-layout col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <div class="product-thumb transition">
    <div class="image"><a href="#"><img src="../image/cache/catalog/savouries/karasevu-200x200.jpg" alt="Karasevu" title="Karasevu" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    <div class="caption">
      <h4><a href="#">Karasevu</a></h4>
      <p class="price"> $0.00 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-group home-btn">
      <button class="producthome-btn" type="button" onClick="cart.add('71');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart cart-icon"></i> <span class="">Add to Cart</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second Div structure

```
<div class="more-link product-layout col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="a-more-link"> <a href="#">VIEW MORE</a> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `background-size` property.

```
.someClass {
    background-image: url(someImage.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First method use **`background-size`** to **100%**

```
.classname {
    background-image: url(img.png);
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Second method use **`background-size`** to **cover**

```
.classname {
    background-image: url(img.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using background-size:cover and you can center it by using background-position:center

Answer (score 0):

Set your body element to 100% like this:

```
 body{
 height: 100%;
}
```

then use inherit or set your bg height to 100% like this:

```
.yourParentDiv{
 height: 100%;
 // your other code here
}
```